# How to rotate a mesh which is part of a multi meshed object without losing original origin

Tags: edit-mode

I have a complex object (building with a ramp to the front door) made of many meshes and the origin and 3D cursor are at a position I don't want to loose (not sure how I set them to where they currently are).

I want to rotate a mesh (it is the ramp) with its origin set to the end which intersects with the building) however if I reset the origin to that position I will loose the original location of the origin.

I can set the 3d cursor and the set the origin to the 3d cursor but then I have lost both the original 3D cursor and the original origin.

I guess what I am asking is  - is it possible to save an origin?

How do I do this?

Comment: You can add an empty object to the current cursor location to save that position. You can then parent multiple objects to any empty to rotate them about that coordinate without changing their true origins

Comment: Thanks Duarte. That worked well. I was starting to wonder if I should 'extract' the 'ramp' to a separate blender file, make the rotation and save then append the blender file into the original - not sure if that would work though,   Anyway I now have achieved what I wanted to do, thanks again.